# Using texliveonfly in TeXLive 2011

Tags: texlive

I test [texliveonfly](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg04325.html) using the [tikzpagenodes package](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg04268.html).

```
%fly.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[blue] (current page text area.south west)
    rectangle
    (current page text area.north east)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I typed

```
sudo python texliveonfly.py --texlive_bin=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ fly.tex
```

But error message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tlmgr is not installed
```

What do I do? In short, as its use `texliveonfly` in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/`

Comment: I don't have `texliveonlfy.pl` so I can only guess. You have to provide the full path to the tlmgr (without tlmgr itself). So it is more like `sudo python texliveonfly.py --texlive_bin=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bin/linux/ fly.tex`. To find out the correct dir, type `type -p tlmgr` on the command line.

Comment: Can you explain, please? I could not.

Comment: Explain what? From the error message I have deduced that `texliveonfly` looks for `tlmgr` in the path given to `--texlive_bin`. That's all. Have you tried what I have written? What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

the script is installed as `texliveonfly` with TeXLive 2011. So simply run

```
texliveonfly fly.tex
```

and it should work! At least it did it for me :-)

`texliveonfly` is a link in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/<system>/` 
to the python script `../../texmf-dist/scripts/texliveonfly/texliveonfly.py`

Comment: Herbert, can you explain, please? I could not.

Comment: I already did it ... If you have problems then ask for a specific problem.

Comment: can you explain me step by step, please do not get yet.